# Solve this with CBS: minimum value of $ 1/x + 4/y + 9/z $ with $x+y+z=1$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

How can you see the minimum value of $ 1/x + 4/y + 9/z $ with $x+y+z=1$ using the CBS inequality?

I have seen a proof of that that use trigonometric substitutions, but I don't see as one-step the solution using the CBS inequality.

Comment: Rather similar question: [If $a+b+c=6$ and $a,b,c$ belongs to positive reals $\mathbb{R}^+$; then find the minimum value of $\frac{1}{a}+\frac{4}{b}+\frac{9}{c}$ .](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2413994#2413994)

Answer (score 6):

Consider **positive** values $x,y,z$.

Denote 
$$(a,b,c)=\left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}, \frac{2}{\sqrt{y}}, \frac{3}{\sqrt{z}}\right),$$
$$(A,B,C)=\left( \sqrt{x}, \sqrt{y}, \sqrt{z}\right),$$

then (by CBS inequality)
$$(a^2+b^2+c^2)(A^2+B^2+C^2)\ge (aA+bB+cC)^2,$$
so
$$
\left(\frac{1}{x}+\frac{4}{y}+\frac{9}{z}\right) \left(x+y+z\right)\ge (1+2+3)^2=36;
$$
$$
\frac{1}{x}+\frac{4}{y}+\frac{9}{z}\ge 36.
 $$ (I have added the square)

Comment: If one of $x,y,z$ is negative, then minimum value can be as large as you want: just take $x=-\dfrac{1}{M}$, $y=\dfrac{1}{2}+\dfrac{1}{M}$, $z=\dfrac{1}{2}$.

Comment: I think a square in the right side of your inequality is missing, and with that the minimun is 36, wich is the correct answer

Comment: @Julio, oh, yes. Thank you for correction!

Answer (score 0):

You can also take a look at lagrange multiplier because it is helpful finding where the inequalties are sharp and what are the maximal minimal values when dealing with reel numbers (without the restriction of positive-negative);

So let me introduce $k$ that is the lagrange multiplier;

$f(x,y,z,k)=\dfrac1x+\dfrac4y+\dfrac9z+k(x+y+z-1)$ we will try to minimize this expression using what we know about $x,y,z$ ; Take the derivatives in respect to all variables;

$$f_k'=0$$
$$f_x'=k-\frac{1}{x^2}$$
$$f_y'=k-\dfrac{4}{y^2}$$
$$f_z'=k-\dfrac{9}{z^2}$$

All these derivatives are equal to $f_k'=0$ so we can say;

$$k=\frac{1}{x^2}=\frac{4}{y^2}=\frac{9}{z^2}$$
$$\sqrt{k}=\frac1x=\frac2y=\frac3z=\frac{1+2+3}{x+y+z}$$
$$\sqrt{k}=\frac61=6$$
So $x=\dfrac16$--$y=\dfrac26$--$z=\dfrac36=\dfrac12$

$\frac1x=6+\frac4y=12+\frac9z=18=36$ 
Done!

Comment: "18=36"?? It's hard to take this seriously when you end like that.